# Haproxy log each frontend to different file with rsyslog

Tags: linux, haproxy, rsyslog

I have many frontends in haproxy, I plan to log each frontend to different file, for example, frontend a to /var/log/a.log, b to /var/log/b.log, but haproxy's log facility must be one of the 24 standard syslog facilities, is possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable using rsyslog filters. You can filter the messages based on frontend IP/port and then write these messages to a separate log file.